# How to pass data to a text field - FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, textfield, calculator

```
**[![I want to achieve this, where a calculator input is shown to the user, and the user input and output of calculations is shown inside the text field
```

Please give me suggestions how can I achieve this functionality... ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu7Q9.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu7Q9.jpg)**

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a controller to the text field and then you can change the text of that controller using the following statement

```
_controller.text="Your Text goes here";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you ask more questions or detailed pictures of the initial state and what you want to achieve?

if you want to pass data into a text field you can use Controller
initialization controller example

```html
TextEditingController _yourcontrollerName1 = TextEdititingController;
```

inside the widget textfield :

```html
TextField(
..
controller :_yourcontrollerName1
)
```

you can set data with

```html
_yourcontrollerName1.text = your_data_pass
```

or

```html
TextEditingController _yourcontrollerName1 = TextEditingController(text:data_your_pass);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Basically  I want to achieve a functionality where user can enter their daily debits and credits of their shops, for that I want to provide them a calculator as a input type and all the calculations should be performed inside the text field where user can see those calculations. Hope you get my point